# Coveo Suggested Results Returning the Wrong URL on Search View

Tags: coveo

We are using this to provide suggested results on our search view page.
[https://developers.coveo.com/display/SitecoreV4/Provide+Result+Suggestions](https://developers.coveo.com/x/CIIUAg)

However the results provided are returning a URL that has an extra value in it that is not the correct path to the item returned.  We are also using the suggested results tied to Search Box View and there the URL is correct.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Correct URL from the Search Box View Suggest results 
https://server/en/locations/item

Incorrect URL from the Search View page.  Note it is adding our "home" node in to the url.
https://server/en/**home**/locations/item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum, I believe there might be an error in the documentation.

This line:

```
<a href="{{-ClickUri}}" class="title open-link">{{-Title}}</a>
```

Should be this line:

```
<a href="{{-clickUri}}" class="title open-link">{{-Title}}</a>
```

The slight difference is the "c" of click uri. The ClickUri is what is in the index. When a result is returned, Coveo for Sitecore uses the REST Endpoint Pipeline to add a new clickUri attribute which is the original ClickUri adjusted to the context of the site. For more information on the clickUri vs ClickUri, please read:

[https://developers.coveo.com/display/SitecoreV4/Understanding+How+The+ClickableUri+Value+Is+Computed](https://developers.coveo.com/x/2ADvAQ)

TLDR: Change the ClickUri to clickUri in the result template of the Coveo Result list.

Comment: Also see this post that explains the difference between all the URIs in a JSON search result : https://answers.coveo.com/questions/7586/rest-api-uri-hell